# SonarQube - Exception in Report about progress of ActionScript analyzer

Tags: sonarqube

I have an error while executing sonarqube on some projects contining javasript:

```
Exception in thread "Report about progress of ActionScript analyzer" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.javascript.ProgressReport.run(ProgressReport.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

SonarQube is installed and I have already analyzed other projects.

Any idea of what I should check?